# Different output from the same Go program

Tags: go

Here is my Go code: http://play.golang.org/p/CDUagFZ-rk

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var max int = 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        var len int = GetCollatzSeqLen(i)
        if len > max {
            max = len
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(max)

}

func GetCollatzSeqLen(n int) int {
    var len int = 1
    for n > 1 {
        len++
        if n%2 == 0 {
            n = n / 2
        } else {
            n = 3*n + 1
        }
    }
    return len

}
```

On my local machine, when I run the program, I get 525 as the output. When I run it on the Go Playground, the output is 476.

I am wondering what's different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the implementation-specific size of `int`, 32 or 64 bits. Use `int64` for consistent results. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var max int64 = 0
    for i := int64(0); i < 1000000; i++ {
        var len int64 = GetCollatzSeqLen(i)
        if len > max {
            max = len
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(max)

}

func GetCollatzSeqLen(n int64) int64 {
    var len int64 = 1
    for n > 1 {
        len++
        if n%2 == 0 {
            n = n / 2
        } else {
            n = 3*n + 1
        }
    }
    return len

}
```

Output:

```
525
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/0Cdic16edP

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> ```
>  int32       the set of all signed 32-bit integers (-2147483648 to 2147483647)
>  int64       the set of all signed 64-bit integers (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
> ```
>
> The value of an n-bit integer is n bits wide and represented using
>   two's complement arithmetic.
>
> There is also a set of predeclared numeric types with
>   implementation-specific sizes:
>
> ```
>  uint     either 32 or 64 bits
>  int      same size as uint
> ```

To see the implementation-specific size of `int`, run this program.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        "For "+runtime.GOARCH+" the implementation-specific size of int is",
        strconv.IntSize, "bits.",
    )
}
```

Output:

```
For amd64 the implementation-specific size of int is 64 bits.
```

On Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/7O6dEdgDNd

```
For amd64p32 the implementation-specific size of int is 32 bits.
```

Comment: If you play around enough you could hit a number where n goes above even 2^64. [`math/big`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) can handle such numbers, at the cost of slower computation and more verbose code.